# Error on starting .NET Core Web API on IIS: "Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server"

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have published `.NET Core` 2.2 API to `IIS` v.10 and for some reason it responds 500!

I tried

- stdoutLogEnabled="true" (didn't generate the log file )
- app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage (nothing)
- dotnet.exe x.dll where x is project name (said: no listening endpoints were configured. binding to http://localhost:5000) then it works perfectly on 5000 instead of the specified port on IIS

I would appreciate your advice. Thanks

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

`launchSettings.json` file:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5694",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "x": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5694",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Startup:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration(String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/nlog.config"));
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I have reinstalled the `.NET Core` bundle and I got this from `stdout`:

```
Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception
System.InvalidOperationException: Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[2]
      Failed to locate the development https certificate at '(null)'.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer[1]
      Unable to locate an appropriate development https certificate.
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      No listening endpoints were configured. Binding to http://localhost:5000 by default.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\VetWorkAdmin
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[4]
      Hosting started
dbugNow listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[0]
      Loaded hosting startup assembly VetWork.Admin
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[0]
      Loaded hosting startup assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration
```

Comment: Do you have the [IIS .NET Core hosting bundle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iis-configuration) installed and set up?

Comment: Also ensure you have installed the `Development time IIS support` package in the Visual Studio installer under `ASP.NET and web development`

Comment: i remembered that our admin pushed windows update so i reinstalled the .netcore bundle and update the post with stdout log ... please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

For `InProcess` it uses `IISHttpServer`. Check [Host your ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web App with IIS (in-process and out-of-process hosting model) and deploy to Docker Windows Containers](https://appdevmusings.com/host-your-asp-net-core-2-2-web-app-with-iis-in-process-and-out-of-process-hosting-model-and-deploy-to-docker-windows-containers) explaining the details.

Answer (score 6):

If Your'e experiencing thiss use when hosting app as an Azure App Service

Add this:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

under

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
```

inside your host `*.csproj` file.

Comment: [REVIEW] That could be nice information for Azure users Marcin, but I'm downvoting, because it is not an answer to the question. The question clearly states: "IIS" and "localhost".

Comment: @Goodies I upvoted this, because I had exactly the same error on IIS on the server machine and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APP_POOL_ID") is not null)
{
    builder.WebHost.UseIIS();
}
```